# How to append a number to the end of a duplicated line containing a pattern with sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I have a .txt file containing:

```
>ABC
hello
>ABC
thanks
>ABC
for
>ABC
your
>ABC
help
```

I want to change duplicate strings containing ">" to:

```
>ABC_1
hello
>ABC_2
thanks
>ABC_3
for
>ABC_4
your
>ABC_5
help
```

Comment: Why not `hello_1` and/or `help_1`

Comment: hello and help are not duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print $0 (/^>/ ? "_" (++c) : "")}' file
>ABC_1
hello
>ABC_2
thanks
>ABC_3
for
>ABC_4
your
>ABC_5
help
```

If the first field can vary and you want a unique count per first field value then you just make the count an array indexed by the first field:

```
$ cat file
>ABC
hello
>FOO
thanks
>ABC
for
>ABC
your
>FOO
help

$ awk '{print $0 (/^>/ ? "_" (++c[$1]) : "")}' file
>ABC_1
hello
>FOO_1
thanks
>ABC_2
for
>ABC_3
your
>FOO_2
help
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  NR==FNR && index($0, ">")==1 { a[$0]++ }
  NR!=FNR && a[$0]>1 { $0=$0"_"(++b[$0]) }
  NR!=FNR
' file file
```

When `file` is read the first time, increment a counter in array `a` for each line that starts with `>`.
When `file` is read the second time, test if the counter for given line is greater one. If true, increment counter in array `b`
and append suffix `_` and the counter value. Then print the line.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you

Comment: That's far more complicated and inefficient than necessary to just do this task. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566490/133219

Comment: Agreed. Nice solution @EdMorton! But your solution is different in that it counts every line with starting with a `>` while mine also distinguishes the content of the field (which is irrelevant for given input since the line is always `>ABC`).

Comment: If the first field can vary and you want a unique count per first field value then you just make the count an array indexed by the first field, `print $0 (++c[$1])`. I just updated my answer to show that too.

Comment: Yes, but that would add the count to every line and not to duplicate lines only and you only know if the line occurs one or more times if the file has been fully read. It's not clear if OP really wants this, but at least that's what I thought.